# Download folder from Google Cloud using Gsutil

Tags: download, cloud, gsutil

I'm trying to download a folder from my bucket in Google Cloud Services to a folder on my local desktop using this command in a Google Cloud SDK shell

gsutil -m cp -r gs://synology-flashstation-liveprojects/SP_35xx/SP-3520_SCAPE_LOGO_ANIMATION/Project_File/ Desktop\3520_Scape

I don't get an error message, the cursor just returns to the prompt: C:\Users\Skeleton 7\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>#

Can anyone help?
Thanks,
Merrin.

Comment: Hi Merrin. In order to have more details about the issue you are getting, please execute the same command you are using and add at the end the "verbosity" flag to get more details. The command must look like this "gsutil -m cp -r gs://synology-flashstation-liveprojects/SP_35xx/SP-3520_SCAPE_LOGO_ANIMATION/Project_File/ Desktop\3520_Scape --verbosity=debug". Please, share the output of the command.

Comment: Hi Samuel, thank you for your response. I really appreciate it. I added that flag and this is what it returned: CommandException: No URLs matched: Desktop\3520_Scape
CommandException: Destination URL must name a directory, bucket, or bucket
subdirectory for the multiple source form of the cp command.
CommandException: 2 files/objects could not be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in my response.

The error message you are getting is because the path where you trying to download the files does not exist. You should double check that the path is correct.

As I can see, you are executing it from a Windows machine, so, instead of use `"Desktop\3520_Scape"` use the full path. Something like `"c:\users\myUser\Desktop"`.

This should work.

Comment: Hi Samuel, The problem was because I was copying to Windows. In order for the download to work, you have to adjust some of the characters in the Windows file path...  Move entire command (copied from Google Cloud console) onto a single line - easiest to do this in notepad
Remove all \
Make sure there is only a single space between parameters
Ensure gs filepath is wrapped in double quotes
Remove the final / in the filepath before the closing double quotation
Change directory to where you want so copy the folder
- You can use cd /d G:/ to change to the G:/ drive
Execute the command

Comment: Sorry the above is brief. There's a character limit. Thanks so much for your help.